# Binding won't update when objects change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array that is, basically, a subset of another array:

```
$scope.theFew = $scope.theMany.filter(function(obj, index, array) {
   return obj.IsVerySpecial;
});
```

Elsewhere in my controller, I have some functions that act on `theMany` array, changing the `IsVerySpecial` property.

I'd expect `$scope.theFew` to update when objects within `$scope.theMany` have their properties change, but that isn't the case. What's going on?

Comment: How are the items in `$scope.theMany` being updated?

Answer (score 0):

A quick discovery on this, but it worked. To be fair, this was some older code ;)

The code should instead read:

```
$scope.theFew = function() {
  return $scope.theMany.filter(function(obj, index, array) {
     return obj.IsVerySpecial;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar issue. I have used the $watch to update scope variables. Not sure if this is the best way.

```
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
        updateVisualData();

        $scope.$watch("data", function(newData) {
            console.log("new Data in paContent");
            console.log(newData);
            updateVisualData();
        }, true);

        function updateVisualData() {
            var contentData = $scope.data.components && $scope.data.components.filter(function(item) {
                return item.type === "Layout";
            });
            if (contentData && contentData.length > 0) {
                contentData = contentData[0];
                $scope.graphType = contentData.graph.type;
                $scope.graphData = contentData.graph.graphData;
                -----
            }
        }
    }]
```